# Using a local Socks proxy for intercepting traffic and adding custom headers

Tags: networking, tcp, proxy, socks5

My usecase is to build a library that inserts a PPV2 header that the client (using the library) would provide. I want this to library to be as language agnostic as possible. Would it be possible to run a local proxy server that takes some config and adds this header?

I was thinking of using a SOCKS proxy server and perhaps use the username/pass field for metadata. Since its a library, there wouldn't be a need for Auth anyways. But I'm not sure if using the username field like this is a good idea.
Is there a better approach?